# Could somebody translate this into modern English?

Tags: poetry, meaning

This was extracted from Book I of the Iliad by Homer (translated by Samuel Butler):

> Therefore I say, and swear it with a great oath- nay, by this my
>   sceptre which shalt sprout neither leaf nor shoot, nor bud anew from
>   the day on which it left its parent stem upon the mountains-

Could somebody translate this into modern English.

PS: English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: It might be better if you supplied a complete sentence. As it is, I see little particularly archaic in the extract you have supplied.

Comment: Um, that ***is*** written in Modern English, specifically Early Modern English.

Comment: What you really are trying to ask, I gather, is "Could somebody rephrase this in simple English?"  In which case, this is not going to be the site for you.  If you have specific problems with one or more words, ask away.  But ELU.SE won't bulk translate/proof read stuff.

Comment: This is the ***Iliad***. There are [a myriad of translations.](https://books.google.com/books?id=fM4int9lNeUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+iliad&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x036VJqDLcmzggSlr4CIDg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20iliad&f=false) Why are you reading this one if you can't understand it?  "But hear me. I swear a solemn oath to you now: that by this staff which has never since the day it was cut down deep in the mountains ..."

Comment: @tchrist Not EME, although it is mildly (by contemporary standards) archaicizing: Butler's Iliad was published in 1898, pretty much the high-water mark of ModE.

Comment: And the [Alexander Pope translation](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/6130/6130-h/6130-h.html#toc5): Now by this sacred sceptre hear me swear,
Which never more shall leaves or blossoms bear,
Which sever'd from the trunk (as I from thee)
On the bare mountains left its parent tree;

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, I know now. I realized that Butler was Victorian.

Comment: @PeterShor  The Pope is very nice; what can be said against it? For EME, there’s always Hobbes.

Comment: @PeterShor: The force-fitting of the original scansion into heroic couplets, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps the *Iliad* has been translated into your native language...

Comment: @GEdgar Towards that purpose the [translation by Odorico Mendes](http://www.ebooksbrasil.org/adobeebook/iliadap.pdf) will probably serve our poster: *Por este cetro juro, que estroncado /
Jamais rebentará, pois na montanha /
Folhas e casca cerceou-lhe o gume; /
Por este, que os Grajúgenas arvoram /
Do justo guarda e das leis divinas, /
Juro, Atrida, é solene o juramento, /
Suspirarão sem falta por Aquiles; /
Nem lhes serás de auxílio, quando em barda /
Esse Heitor homicida os vá segando. /
Então de raiva e nojo hás de comer-te, /
Porque o maior dos Gregos rebaixaste.*

Comment: I've just woke up and came directly to my computer to check if that was any response to my question. I'm amazed. I was not expecting such diverse and constructive comments to my humble question. I'm really thankful to all. And @tchrist, my special thanks for your suggestion of Odorico Mendes translation, although I intend to continue with Butler's translation. Just by reading the few lines you reproduced above I can see how archaic is the Portuguese used by Mr. Mendes. But I'll probably use it, from now on, as another source, to help me better understand the Iliad. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** A 1990 translation is provided as the last citation at the bottom.

---

You have it easy compared to those many of us who struggled to read that epic song of rage with words beginning thus:

> μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
> οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε
> πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν
> ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν
> οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,
> ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε
> Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.

But instead of that, you have the advantage of reading Modern English in the Latin alphabet.  Samuel Butler was a Victorian, a ***19ᵗʰ century*** poet: you can hardly claim that he did not write in Modern English!

If you cannot read the English of little more than a hundred years ago, you need more experience, not a rewrite into little words and short sentences.

This is the more complete context surrounding the Samuel Butler quote you cited:

> Therefore I say, and swear it with a great oath – nay, by this my sceptre which shalt sprout neither leaf nor shoot, nor bud anew from the day on which it left its parent stem upon the mountains – for the axe stripped it of leaf and bark, and now the sons of the Achaeans bear it as judges and guardians of the decrees of heaven – so surely and solemnly do I swear that hereafter they shall look fondly for Achilles and shall not find him.  In the day of your distress, when your men fall dying by the murderous hand of Hector, you shall not know how to help them, and shall rend your heart with rage for the hour when you offered insult to the bravest of the Achaeans.”

As noted by StoneyB in comments, this is “archaizing” — using archaic forms like *shalt* for deliberate effect, despite having been transcribed “quite recently” (well, compared with the original :).

To show you that that is indeed Modern English, let us step back a few centuries to the 17ᵗʰ century translation by Thomas Hobbes, which was still Modern English, albeit of that rarefied vintage we now call Early Modern English:

> But this I’ll say, and with an oath make good.
> (Now by this sceptre, which hath left behind
> The stock whereon it once grew in the wood,
> And never more shall have nor leaf nor rind,
> And by Achæan princes now is borne
> By whom Jove’s laws to th’ people carried be.)
> You hear now what a great oath I have sworn:
> If ere the Acheans shall have need of me,
> And Agamemnon cannot them relieve,
> When Hector fills the field with bodies slain,
> And Agamemnon only for them grieve,
> They my assistance wish for shall in vain.

That’s rather nice, although some sins have been taken *causa metri*; they always are when trying to stick to a particular metrical system.

The 18ᵗʰ century poet Alexander Pope also reads more nicely than the Butler in my humble opinion. Like the verse of Hobbes, that of Pope also rhymes — or did so when he wrote it:

> Now by this sacred sceptre hear me swear,
> Which never more shall leaves or blossoms bear,
> Which sever’d from the trunk (as I from thee)
> On the bare mountains left its parent tree;
> This sceptre, form’d by temper’d steel to prove
> An ensign of the delegates of Jove,
> From whom the power of laws and justice springs
> (Tremendous oath! inviolate to kings);
> By this I swear:— when bleeding Greece again
> Shall call Achilles, she shall call in vain.
> When, flush’d with slaughter, Hector comes to spread
> The purpled shore with mountains of the dead,
> Then shall thou mourn the affront thy madness gave,
> Forced to deplore when impotent to save:
> Then rage in bitterness of soul to know
> This act has made the bravest Greek thy foe.”

As any can plainly see, the Pope is more felicitous than the Butler in many ways, although not for purity of the Greek, an oddity Butler also displayed by his mixing of Latin names with Greek ones within the same tale.

The 20ᵗʰ century poet Robert Fables dispenses with that nonsense and calls a Zeus a Zeus in his free-verse translation, no longer bound to rhyme’s chain:

> I tell you this, and I swear a mighty oath upon it . . . 
> by this, this scepter, look,
> that never again will put forth crown and branches,
> now it’s left its stump on the mountain ridge forever,
> nor will it sprout new green again, now the brazen ax
> has stripped its bark and leaves, and now the sons of Achaea
> pass it back and forth as they hand their judgments down,
> upholding the honored customs whenever Zeus commands—
> someday, I swear, a yearning for Achilles will strike
> Achaea’s sons and all your armies! But then, Atrides,
> harrowed as you will be, *nothing* you can do can save you—
> not when your hordes of fighters drop and die,
> cut down by the hands of man-killing Hector! Then—
> then you will tear your heart out, desperate, raging
> that you disgraced the best of the Achaeans!”

And there I end this history, for the Robert Fagles translation is from 1990, and no poet of note has yet published a translation in English during this the 21ˢᵗ century.  Let then the Fagles serve as the modern English version you requested, and therefore the answer to your request (which was not a question, you see, but a request).

Read whichever one you will — and can.  But you cannot just ask for such a huge paraphrasing of things you do not understand. Pin it down to a phrase, a word, an idiom that escapes you, and we will be glad to try to help you.

However, if one cannot do that, then one is attempting a work that is beyond one, and so one must study more before one dare attempt it again.

But I do advise attempting it again.

### Edited to Add

Here is the [interlinear translation of those lines of the epic by Thomas Clarke](https://archive.org/stream/iliadhomerwitha00clargoog#page/n4/mode/2up) from 1888, published before the Samuel Butler. It is not especially archaicizing apart from the *thou*-forms of the verbs and pronouns which we no longer use, but it is quite literal. It may, however, be of some insight:

[image: iliad clip 1]
[image: iliad clip 2]

Since you are Brazilian, the [translation of 1799 by your countryman Odorico Mendes into the Portuguese of his era](http://www.ebooksbrasil.org/adobeebook/iliadap.pdf) might better avail you:

> Por este cetro juro, que estroncado
> Jamais rebentará, pois na montanha
> Folhas e casca cerceou-lhe o gume;
> Por este, que os Grajúgenas arvoram
> Do justo guarda e das leis divinas,
> Juro, Atrida, é solene o juramento,
> Suspirarão sem falta por Aquiles;
> Nem lhes serás de auxílio, quando em barda
> Esse Heitor homicida os vá segando.
> Então de raiva e nojo hás de comer-te,
> Porque o maior dos Gregos rebaixaste.”

I recognize that the style of the Portuguese of 1799 is also older, but so too would be the English of 1799. Still, it should be easier on your eye than the Hobbes or Pope.  Plus I’m sure that even if you yourself as a Brazilian don’t use *tu*-forms of the verbs or place your object pronouns after finite verbs any longer in Brazil the way they still do those things in Portugal, you will nonetheless have little trouble reading its older Portuguese.

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with your dogs—I don't recall there being an 88 in their midst. ;-)

Comment: Great answer. What else can I say? Congratulations. I went to see your profile here in ELU and found out that we have something in common beyond my curiosity with the Classis. I'm also working my way into C++ and have been using SO for my questions on the subject (+1).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, there were a lot of them. Perhaps I could enumerate the raptors, too. :)

Comment: @Belloc I’ve added an especially literal interlinear translation of the original, which although it has 2nd-person pronouns and verb forms, may be easier to understand that the prose version of Butler.

Comment: Thanks for the extra-material you indicated above. But I'll stick with Butler's translation. Just to give you an idea about the difficulties of using the Portuguese translation by Odorico Mendes, I call your attention to the fact that he translated "the sons of the Achaeans" as "Grajúgenas", and that doesn't make any sense to me. As far as I can tell, this word [doesn't exist in Portuguese](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=graj%FAgenas).

Comment: @Belloc I had already noticed that some of the proper nouns seems oddly translated. I didn’t read through much of it in Portuguese, though, just the start and the part pertaining to your citation.

Comment: @LittleEva: Brief for tchrist, perhaps.

Comment: @Robusto - EXACTLY!

Comment: @Robusto, I take that back, I just noticed tchrist doubled the text while I was making a cup of tea!

Comment: It may double yet again if you don't keep an eye on it.